# Expo/React Native Fetch API is not returning text/plain data

Tags: javascript, react-native, xmlhttprequest, expo, fetch-api

I am trying to load a text/plain file from a public S3 bucket. Currently fetch is returning a successful response code and expected response headers, but `response.text()` is giving undefined.

Expo Version: 30

It's not S3 related either because trying to get a text/html document from google fails as well.

```
let resp = await fetch("https://google.com")
console.log(resp);
let txt = await resp.text();
console.log(txt); //undefined
```

This has me utterly confused as my fetch calls to my REST API return valid responses when decoded with `response.json()` and I'm wondering if anyone has had a similar problem/solutions. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide an example that reproduces this? I just copied your code to https://snack.expo.io and it worked as expected - https://snack.expo.io/@notbrent/fetch

Comment: If it works there maybe it's a problem with the expo version. I can try upgrading from 30->32, it's just so weird that it's not working. That is literally what I have in a function and am calling in componentDidMount()

Comment: It's running Expo version 30 on an iPhone XR simulator

Comment: It seems to be like it is expo version 30, I updated to 32 and it worked. Might be the version of react native required with 30 I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be something to do with Version 30 of Expo or the react native version used with version 30 of expo. Updating Expo and subsequently React Native fixed the issue.